# understanding lodash `.every` behavior

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have this very simple example that I cannot understand why it doesn't work as I would expect.

```
const items = { custom: null, preset: null }
const val = ._every(items, null)
```

This returns `false` why????
Shouldn't this code mean, if every property in the object fulfills this condition then return true?

Comment: it seems _.every is applicable for arrays only, not for objects

Comment: that's not what the documentation says but it does seem like that

Comment: @Andrei no, it's also applicable on objects. But not this way. It either expects a function or object or a path, or a value.  null is something that it can't decide what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For objects you should use a predicate like below :

```js
const items = { custom: null, preset: null }
console.log(_.every(items , e=> e === 42));
console.log(_.every(items , e=> e === null));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

@Michael you are right. Documentation is not mentioning it explicitly. But if you check its method signature it expects `Function` for the second argument and also in those examples, there are some short usage versions of it. Those are :

> // The `_.matches` iteratee shorthand.
> `_.every(users, { 'user': 'barney', 'active': false }); // => false`

> // The `_.matchesProperty` iteratee shorthand.
> `_.every(users, ['active', false]);`
> // => true

> // The `_.property` iteratee shorthand.
> `_.every(users, 'active'); // => false`

So your usage is `_.property` iteratee shorthand. And it expects a property name. Providing `null` value to the property name gives you the result : `false`.

Comment: I appreciate the answer but still do not underwhy `null` is not a valid predicate, there no mention of this limitation in the docs.

Comment: @Michael see the updated answer.